# If $P(x)$ is a degree $d$ polynomial and $w$ is a root of $P(x) - z_0 = 0$, then is $\frac{d}{dx}(P(x)-z_0)|_{x=w}\neq 0$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Let $P(x)$ be a degree $d$ polynomial with complex coefficients and $w_1,\dots,w_d$ be roots of the polynomial $Q(x) = P(x) - z_0$ for some $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$. Then is it true that $\frac{d}{dx}(P(x) - z_0)|_{x=w_i}\neq 0$ for all $i=1,\dots,d$? My intuition says that the claim is not true in general. I encountered this question in my complex analysis notes where the inversion of a polynomial is being discussed. There the non-zeroness of $P'$ is used to conclude that each $w_i$ is simple and hence $w_1,\dots,w_d$ are distinct.

Comment: The value of $z_0$ does not matter. $Q'(w_i) \ne 0$ for all $i=1, \ldots, d$ holds if and only if  $Q$ has only simple zeros, that is if all $w_i$ are distinct.   That need not be the case in general. The simplest counterexample is $Q(z) = z^2$ with $w_1 = w_2 = 0$. –  I assume that some other information is missing (which is used to prove $Q'(w_i) = 0$).

Comment: If $Q(x)$ has $(x-w)^{n}$ , then the Derivative has $(x-w)^{n-1}$ , hence that will **not be** $0$ at $x=w$ when $n=1$ , otherwise it **will still be** $0$ at $x=0$ ! [ **Simple root versus multiple root** ] https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultipleRoot.html